# How can I create a XML file containing the difference in value between another 2 XML files

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015

Hello there C# enthusiast!

I am trying to create an XML file based on the elements subtraction of another two xml files ( the difference in value of elements)
For example:

[The Source Xml files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNNnq.png)

Sought output:

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcT9z.png)

I did a quick research and found that there is a lib for XML content difference but none that fulfill this 
functionality.

I know this can be solved by System.xml class , but I don't know exactly how to start.
Any help is appreciated.

XML Text Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report>
  <Project>
    <Name>P1</Name>
    <Runs>10</Runs>
    <Errors>5</Errors>
    <Successful>5</Successful>
  </Project>
.
. Multiple Projects exists here 
.
  <Project>
    <Name>P2</Name>
    <Runs>12</Runs>
    <Errors>3</Errors>
    <Successful>9</Successful>
  </Project>
  <Timestamp>
    <Year>2020</Year>
    <Month>6</Month>
    <Day>8</Day>
    <Hour>12</Hour>
  </Timestamp>
</Report>
```

Comment: Post text xml sample.  It is very easy to do in xml linq.

Comment: @jdweng I did add text sample as requested, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq.  I assumed you had same Projects in both input and output files.  If not you will need a left outer join. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME_1 = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string INPUT_FILENAME_2 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml2";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME_1);

            DateTime date1 = doc1.Descendants("Timestamp")
                .Select(x => new DateTime(
                    (int)x.Element("Year"),
                    (int)x.Element("Month"),
                    (int)x.Element("Day"),
                    (int)x.Element("Hour"),
                    0, 0)).FirstOrDefault();

            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME_2);

            DateTime date2 = doc2.Descendants("Timestamp")
                .Select(x => new DateTime(
                    (int)x.Element("Year"),
                    (int)x.Element("Month"),
                    (int)x.Element("Day"),
                    (int)x.Element("Hour"),
                    0, 0)).FirstOrDefault();

            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Report></Report>";
            XDocument outputDoc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement outputReport = outputDoc.Root;
            XElement oldReport;
            XElement newReport;
            TimeSpan deltaTime; 

            if (date2 > date1)
            {
                newReport = doc2.Root;
                oldReport = doc1.Root;
                deltaTime = date2.Subtract(date1);
            }
            else
            {
                newReport = doc1.Root;
                oldReport = doc2.Root;
                deltaTime = date1.Subtract(date2);
            }

            var groups = (from n in newReport.Elements("Project")
                          join o in oldReport.Elements("Project")
                          on (string)n.Element("Name") equals (string)o.Element("Name")
                          select new { oldProj = o, newProj = n }
                          ).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                XElement difference = new XElement("Project", new object[] {
                    new XElement("Name", (string)group.newProj.Element("Name")),
                    new XElement("Runs", (int)group.newProj.Element("Runs") - (int)group.oldProj.Element("Runs")),
                    new XElement("Errors", (int)group.newProj.Element("Errors") - (int)group.oldProj.Element("Errors")),
                    new XElement("Successful", (int)group.newProj.Element("Successful") - (int)group.oldProj.Element("Successful"))
                });
                outputReport.Add(difference);
            }

            XElement newTime = new  XElement("Timestamp", new object[] {
                new XElement("Year", 0),
                new XElement("Month", 0),
                new XElement("Day", deltaTime.Days),
                new XElement("Hour", deltaTime.Hours)
            });
            outputReport.Add(newTime);

            outputDoc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Such an elegant and effective solution. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I found a limitation to this method. (To be fair it was not mentioned in the question). If the files have the same number of projects & the same order then it works fine, but what if one of them has more or was not in the same order?                                                                 
File 1:(Project A--Project B) ,File 2:(Project B--Project A)                                                            
The var groups wont be able to find the match in this case, but clearly both files have Project A and Project B. Can we iterate one per all to find a match ?

Comment: Read the 1st line of my answer.  I said you may need to use a Left Outer Join.  In this case you need two joins  1) n join o 2) o join n. [sometimes called a Right Join]  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: Ah I see ! I never heard of left outer join term before, so I missed the information. I will have a look. Thank you and wish you a great day.

Comment: The join doesn't care about the order.  I'm not sure how you want to handle duplicates.   You may want to use a group by to get the duplicates.